# JS - Jquery Selection is confusing

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I thought a lot about a better headline, but... yeah kinda came to none describing my problem.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="chatrooms">
    <div class="chatroom active" id="all">all</div>
    <div class="chatroom" id="245332"></div>
</div>
```

Note that I use the classes "chatrooms" and "chatroom" - so dont get confused

```
$(document).on('click', ".chatroom", function(e){
    var id = e.target.id;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.chatrooms > .chatroom#' + id).addClass('active'); //doesn't work
    $('.chatrooms').children('#' + id).addClass('active'); //doesn't work
    $(this).addClass('active'); //works
});
```

So only one of this 3 methods works, but I need at least one not working one, because I have multiple divs outside ".chatrooms" with the id. I hope you can help me! Thanks for your time!

Comment: You've told us what doesn't work, but not what you're actually trying to achieve...?

Comment: i also told you what works - so also what I want to achieve :) I want to add a class to the element with class: 'chatroom' and the id: var id in .chatrooms

Comment: Well if you have something that works, what's the question?

Comment: The question is exposed so badly that it is slightly impossible to understand that the issue is that **none** of the two "doesn't work" lines don't work and, hence, that the user need at least one of them working (" but I need at least one not working one"). Anyway, it should be #chatrooms instead of .chatrooms, because chatrooms is an ID; not a class.

Comment: Just a little side note: don't re-use IDs

Comment: ... its below the code...  I only want the .chatroom in .chatrooms get the 'active' class

Comment: Why would you *not* want to use `$(this)` to add your "active" class, given that you are obviously trying to add it to the clicked item? (Other than to understand how to use those other selectors purely for learning purposes.)

Comment: @briosheje that's the problem :) that chatrooms is an id! thx

Comment: I'll try to explain it again :) I bind the click event to document, because if my script is read the .chatroom element doesn't even exist!; Additionally I dont want .chatroom#id elements outside #chatrooms to get the 'active' class - that's why I need that weird selector :)

Comment: Since IDs are unique per document, why bother with "the element of id x that is in an element of class y that has an element of class z as a child" rather than "the element of id x" only.  So $("#" + id) would be an appropriate selector.  But just use $(this) and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If I read this correctly, `chatrooms` is your div's id, not class. So the jQuery selector should be `#chatrooms` instead of `.chatrooms`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here. First, you're trying to target your 'chatrooms' ID with `.chatrooms`. jQuery uses CSS selectors to target elements, so the correct format for targeting IDs is `#chatrooms`.

Next you're using '`.chatrooms > .chatroom#`' which means "target all elements with the **CLASS** of `chatroom#` that are direct (first-level) children of all elements with the **CLASS** of `chatrooms`."

Since you don't have any elements with the **CLASS** of `chatroom#`, nor do you have any elements with a **CLASS** of `chatrooms` to look for children in, your results are going to be empty.

You can brush up on CSS selectors on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp or on this great practice site http://flukeout.github.io

You should start there and then come back to jQuery.